# Android Compose. Error when I try run the base code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm starting in Android Jetpack Compose. I installed Canary, when I create an Empty Compose Activity and run it without changes (Hello Android!) I have the next error:

```
    Process: com.example.jetpacktest2, PID: 24788
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver.onCreate(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner)"
        at androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.onStateChanged(FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.java:36)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:808)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:19855)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3597)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3604)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3604)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3604)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3604)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2376)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1993)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8459)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1256)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:995)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:887)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1224)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8387)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

I didn't modify anything, it is the base code created by Android. Any help is appreciated.

PS: I load others codes made it on Android Studio (Without compose) and it run without errors.

Comment: Have a look at this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194289155

Comment: Thank you so much. If somebody have same issue, i fixed it updating compose_version to 1.0.0-rc02 and minSDK to 24

Comment: I have same issue . It is the issue of android studio canary build

Comment: No it is not an issue with the Studio. It is an issue with the AGP, which will be fixed in 7.1.0-alpha06. Also, the compose version has nothing to do with it. rc01 will also work just fine

Comment: Just update min SDK to 24. Jetpack Compose will not work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It is the issue of android studio canary build. It is one of the kind of bug of Canary build. So its fix is easy and simple.

Do these steps:

1. Uninstall the canary Android Studio.
2. **Download the latest Android Studio Release Candidate (2020.3.1 RC 1)**

   link: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

[image]

3. It will now work fine as previously.  I fixed my problem the same as this. It will work 100% gurrantee.

Comment: Thank you, I already fixed it updating compose_version to 1.0.0-rc02 and minSDK to 24, but I will keep it in mind for future issues.